# SharePoint REST API filter based on Today's date only and not time. (Similar to IncludeTimeValue=False in CAML query)

Tags: rest, sharepoint-2013

I am trying to get data from SharePoint list with REST API that are created today only.

```
var listName = "Carousel%20News";
var today = new Date().toISOString();
```

Here is my REST URL :

```
_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/items?$select=Id,Title&$filter=Created eq '" + today + "'";
```

**But when I use this rest URL, I am not getting the items that are created today.**

**(I have double checked that there are items present in the list with the today's created date)**

**My assumption is that, this URL filters based on Date and also Time value.**

**So is there way that I can use REST filter with today's date only and ignore the time stamp (like we do `IncludeTimeValue=False` in CAML query)?**

Comment: I am having the same issue

Comment: Added a possible answer below; Let me know if this is helpful.

Comment: a possibility is because you are technically asking for now. you need to reset the hours to 12:00 am to now. modify call variable "Today" adding this: "today.setHours(0,0,0,0);" that will fix your issue

Comment: added answer below: see UTC versus to just string

Answer (score 1):

I do not know how to get this in CAML. However, I recently just got this to work doing this below. I am using an $.ajax query and a for loop to get my data.

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var siteURL = _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl;
    var listName = "Carousel%20News";
   var url = siteURL + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('"+listName+"')/Items";
    $.ajax
    ({
      url: url,
   method: "GET",
   contentType: "application/json; odata=verbose",
   headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
   success: function (data)
      {
        var dateTime = new Date();
        var now = Date.parse(dateTime); //convert dateTime to milliseconds
        for (var i = 0; i < data.d.results.length; i++)
        {
          var item = data.d.results[i];
          var ID = item.ID;
          var Created = item.Created;
          /* Lets get the millisecond value for our Date/Time Column */
          var today = Date.parse(Created); //get Millisecond value for Created Date
          var createdDiff = now - today; // get the date difference between now and Created in Milliseconds
          var formatDateDiff = createdDiff/86400000;
          console.log("Item#: "+ID+", "+"Date Difference (24 hr)= "+formatDateDiff);
          
          //Lets only show the results that meet this criteria
          if(formatDateDiff <= 24){
            // do something with your code
          };
        }
      },
      error: function(data)
      {  
        //Give me an error
      }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Let me know if this solved your issue or helps to get you on the right track

Comment: Can you pls tell, the difference between todays date and another date field.if I wanna compare with a custom_date_field and today's date , whether if its greater than today date  or not..

Answer (score 0):

```js
 var listName = "Carousel%20News";
 var today = new Date();
 //Set the hours for Today
 today.setUTCHours(0,0,0,0); //This will reset today to start from today at 12:00am UTC
 today.toISOString(); //this will return to UTC string

 /*
 today.setHours(0,0,0,0); //This will reset today to local timezone at 12:00 am
 today.toString(); // this will return to YOUR local zimezone string
 */

 var siteURL = _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl;
 var url = siteURL + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/items?$select=Id,Title&$filter=Created eq '" + today + "'"
```